# A new entrypoint in the `@emotion/styled` package, `@emotion/styled/base`, has replaced the `@emotion/styled-base` package

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I am getting the following error and am using the following npm packages,

```
 "react": "^18.2.0",
 "@emotion/react": "^11.1.3",
 "@emotion/styled": "^11.0.0",
 "@emotion/styled-base": "^11.0.0",
 "webpack": "^5.79.0",
 "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
```

@emotion/styled-base got deprecated as per the documentation and it is trying to load the npm package @emotion/styled-base if we delete it.

yarn build is not showing any errors/warnings but it is showing the below error and no component getting loaded when I launch rails application.

Error: A new entrypoint in the `@emotion/styled` package, `@emotion/styled/base`, has replaced the `@emotion/styled-base` package. Please remove this package and use `@emotion/styled/base` instead.

Comment: So did you try that error suggests like instead of "-" use "/"

Comment: I am not using @emotion/styled-base anywhere in the application to try it out, I just included the package @emotion/styled-base in package.json in order to avoid build error (export 'styled' (imported as '_styled') was not found in '@emotion/styled-base' (possible exports: default))

Comment: If you are not using `emotion/styled-base` why is it in your package.json?